# How to remove LinearLayout border in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, border, android-linearlayout

I have a LinearLayout that repeats elements as defined in an Adapter. I've been trying to remove the bottom border, but to no success.

**res/drawable/rev_no_border.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:bottom="-1dp"
        android:left="-1dp"
        android:right="-1dp"
        android:top="-1dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" />
    </item>

    <item
        android:bottom="-1dp"
        android:left="-1dp"
        android:right="-1dp"
        android:top="-1dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" />
    </item>

    <item
        android:bottom="-1dp"
        android:left="-1dp"
        android:right="-1dp"
        android:top="-1dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" />
    </item>

    <item
        android:bottom="-1dp"
        android:left="-1dp"
        android:right="-1dp"
        android:top="-1dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" />
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

This is how I attach the drawable to the Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/revObjectListingWrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/rev_no_border"
    android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
```

What am I not doing?

Vielen dank im voraus.

**UPDATE**

[image]

Comment: LinearLayout has no borders by default. Are you sure the problem is not in the elements you're attaching to that layout? Can you give us an example of such an element?

Comment: @Program-Me-Rev attach screen shot on your post

Comment: post an screenshot of current status

Comment: I just added a screenshot @Mahdi.Pishguy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both ListView and RecyclerView (i don't know which of those you're using) have the ability to have a divider. Basically a small view that gets inserted between each element.

For the ListView, you can use this:

```
android:divider="@null"
android:dividerHeight="0dp"
```

The RecyclerView is a bit more tricky, but you can just google 'android recyclerview remove divider", and then there's plenty of posts about it.

Comment: Many thanks @Moonbloom. That was helpful. It solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Linear Layout does not add any border by default, if you need to add border then you can use drawable .xml file, but you don't need any border in layout the no need to add anything. The normal layout xml is

`<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 </LinearLayout>`

Answer (score -1):

```
android:divider="@null"

android:dividerHeight="0dp"

android:childDivider="@null"
```

you can use in ExanpandleListview to remove borders in your layout.